# argmax_cuda" not implemented for 'Bool

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, torchtext

I am facing this error in google collab. I tried other datatypes like bool tensor but didn't work, please help

**Code**

```
 def _mask(prev_generated_seq):
        prev_mask = torch.eq(prev_generated_seq, 1)
        lengths = torch.argmax(prev_mask,dim=1)
        #test = torch.max(prev_mask,dim=1)
        #lengths = torch.FloatTensor(test)
        max_len = prev_generated_seq.size(1)
        mask = []
        for i in range(prev_generated_seq.size(0)):
            if lengths[i] == 0:
                mask_line = [0] * max_len
            else:
                mask_line = [0] * lengths[i].item()
                mask_line.extend([1] * (max_len - lengths[i].item()))
            mask.append(mask_line)
        mask = torch.ByteTensor(mask)
        if args.cuda:
            mask = mask.cuda()
        return prev_generated_seq.data.masked_fill_(mask, 0)
```

**Error**

```
File "main.py", line 179, in <module>
    train_epoches(abstracts, model, config.epochs, teacher_forcing_ratio=1)
  File "main.py", line 155, in train_epoches
    target_variables, model, teacher_forcing_ratio)
  File "main.py", line 139, in train_batch
    prev_generated_seq = _mask(prev_generated_seq)
  File "main.py", line 101, in _mask
    lengths = torch.argmax(prev_mask,dim=1)
RuntimeError: "argmax_cuda" not implemented for 'Bool'
```

Comment: Did you check the type of `prev_generated_seq` and `prev_mask`?

Answer (score 1):

Your `prev_mask` is a `bool` tensor containing `True` and `False` values since you compare `prev_generated_seq == 1` or `torch.eq(prev_generated_seq, 1)`. Afterward, you use `torch.argmax(prev_mask,dim=1)` which is invalid operation for `bool` tensors.

You can look at this example:

```
import torch
a = torch.zeros((2,2), dtype=torch.bool, device='cuda')
a.argmax(1)
```

> RuntimeError: "argmax_cuda" not implemented for 'Bool'

If your data on cpu not gpu, you get the same mistake but on cpu:

> RuntimeError: "argmax_cpu" not implemented for 'Bool'

**Solution:** you should cast the `bool` tensor to other type e.g. long:

```
prev_mask = torch.eq(prev_generated_seq, 1) * 1
```

or :

```
prev_mask = torch.eq(prev_generated_seq, 1).to(torch.long)
```